# C# Cannot find Rfc2898DeriveBytes contains a constructor that takes 4 arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hash

I have a windows application, the tartget framework is .NET Framework 4.6.1

I use c# to hash passwords. My code is

```
public string HashPassword(string password)
{
    byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8];
    using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        rng.GetBytes(salt);
    }

    string hashed = "";

    using (var rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 100000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512)) 
    {
         //logic implementation

    }
}
```

I got an error CS1729   'Rfc2898DeriveBytes' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments.

I right click on Rfc2898DeriveBytes, then go to the Definition.
In the namespace System.Security.Cryptography, there is
'''public Rfc2898DeriveBytes(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm)'''
'''            : this(new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false).GetBytes(password), salt, iterations, hashAlgorithm)'''

So, why I got the error message? It seems the compiler is looking at somewhere else.

Thank you

Comment: According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-security-cryptography-rfc2898derivebytes-ctor(system-string-system-byte()-system-int32-system-security-cryptography-hashalgorithmname)), that constructor is applicable to .NET Framework 4.7.2 and upper.

Comment: Why don't you just upgrade your target framework version?

Comment: the solution uses many third parties projects, I worry it may cause these projects not working

Comment: If it is not available to 4.6.1, why I right click going to that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Auditive said, Rfc2898DeriveBytes(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm) only supports .NET Framework 4.7.2 and above.

For details, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-security-cryptography-rfc2898derivebytes-ctor(system-string-system-byte()-system-int32-system-security-cryptography-hashalgorithmname)

In addition, as to why you can find this method after clicking "Go to definition" in .net framework 4.7.1, it is because you turned on "Enable navigation to decompiled sources", which caused you to see decompiled code.

Please follow these steps:

Tools=>Options=>Text Editor=>C#=>Advanced=>Uncheck "Enable navigation to decompiled sources"

[image]

Then you will find that there is no Rfc2898DeriveBytes(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm) after going to the definition.